# Std::Array with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, smart-pointers

I have an class which I wish to instantiate by passing an array of values. The object here has two members but this has been reduced for illustration. In the future I will read values from disk and then create an object from those values, hence the array. The object will have multiple pointers later on hence the shared_ptr.

Firstly, I would like to know if this would prevent memory leaks as is. Secondly, I would like to know if there is are less bloated ways of instantiating objects and then determinsitically destroying them later on.

Class Header file:

```
//MyClass.hpp
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <array>

class SimpleClass{
    private:
        //Per object
        double var1;
        double var2;
    public static:
        //For calling when using templates such as std::array<>
        //Using __int8 as will not be > 256
        static const uint8_t varCount 2;
        SimpleBody(std::array<double, varCount> inputArray);
        ~SimpleBody();
}
```

Class Implementation

```
//MyClass.cpp
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <array>
#include "body.hpp"

SimpleBody::SimpleBody(std::array<double, SimpleBody::varCount> inputArray ) {
    //Assign var1
    MyClass::var1= inputArray[0];
    //Assign var2
    MyClass::var2= inputArray[1];
};

SimpleBody::~SimpleBody() {
    //Add in code here when children need deleting
};
```

Entry Point

```
// EntryPoint.cpp
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include <array>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    //Create an array with a smart pointer for memory management
    std::unique_ptr< std::array<double, MyClass::varCount> > initArray =
        std::make_unique< std::array<double, MyClass::varCount> >();
    //Define values
    *initArray = { 1.0,2.0 };
    //Use array to create object
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> object = std::make_shared<MyClass>(*initArray );

    //Free memory
    initArray.reset();
    object.reset();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your question but I think you need to spend some time studying the basics of C++.

Comment: you dont need to manually free the memory of unique and shared ptr. They will do it themself. 
And you always derefernce your unique ptr array. You can just keep it on the stack that way instead of instantiating it on the heap.

Comment: A friend of mine who has worked as a developer for some time once told me that it's better to explicitly free memory when you know you don't need it and then when you forget then the smart_ptr funcionality can act as a safety net. Is that him just being pedantic or are there times when relying on smart_ptr's to free memory can cause memroy leak?

Comment: From what you have shown, there is no need for the smart pointers anyway.

Comment: @Flash_Steel that's just being pedantic. The whole concept behind this RAII view is so that you can forget about them and concentrate on what is important.

Comment: @juanchopanza Objects of MyClass will contain many more members which are non-primitives.

Comment: @Flash_Steel That's not pedantry, it's being silly.

Comment: @Flash_Steel That doesn't matter.

Comment: It's worth resetting unique_ptr etc early if they are pointing to large amounts of data, *and* the variable is going to be long lived.  In this case, I wouldn't bother - it just adds complexity to your code

Comment: Rather than release early I think it would be better to limit the *scope* of the smart pointers. Otherwise you can end up dereferencing null smart pointers or having to always check if they are not null. My suggestion would be, as far as possible, create them as not-null and don't null them before their scope ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you could skip the unique pointer because you only want the values anyway

```
int main()
{
    std::array<double, MyClass::varCount> initArray = { 1.0,2.0 };
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> object = std::make_shared<MyClass>(initArray );
    return 0;
}
```

This would do the same.

For "less bloated":

There is always `auto`:

```
int main()
{
    auto initArray = std::make_unique< std::array<double,  MyClass::varCount> >();
    *initArray = {1.0,2.0};
    auto object = std::make_shared<MyClass>(*initArray );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Less bloated could well be `MyClass({{1., 2.}});`. Difficult to say because most of OP's code seems to have no reason.

Comment: well I assumed the shared_ptr necessary and that you put an array in there. But year for OP code this would be the least code.

Answer (score 2):

First of all its bad if you pass the array by value in the SimpleBody constructor. Better use a reference

```
 SimpleBody(const std::array<int, varCount> &inputArray);
```

At the moment, you construct your shared_ptr the unique_ptr looses the ownership of the array. You don't need to do reset manually. Also, at the moment, your program hits the } line, the memory will be freed.